# "En voilà une idée qu'elle est bonne !" vs "En voilà une idée qui est bonne !"

Tags: sens

> En voilà une idée **qu'elle est bonne** !

Grammatically speaking, "que" cannot strictly refer to any word in this sentence, as opposed to, for instance, the following sentence where "que" refers to the noun "idée":

> En voilà une idée **qu**'on n'avait pas vue venir.

... unless, of course, the emphatic expression "Qu'elle est bonne !" is intended here. But even so, I still find this sentence construction "En voilà une idée qu'elle est bonne !" curious, with no punctuation in between.

The following construction would come more naturally to non-native speakers:

> En voilà une idée **qui est bonne** !

So I wonder if and how these two similarly structured sentences carry subtle nuances of meaning.

Comment: It is indeed something people say (like some sort of catchphrase, in my mind it is associated to Coluche but I'm not sure) but you are right, it is not  standard French because you should' t repeat *elle* after the relative pronoun. And I would never use it in writing.

Comment: @Laure Hi. So... 1) Is the emphatic expression "Qu'elle est bonne !" indeed intended in this sentence? 2) Can this non-standard construction apply to any other example, as long as it takes the form of "***En voilà {noun} qu'il/elle est {adjective} !***"?

Comment: @Laure I wonder if the same can be said for: "En voilà une idée ***qu'elle fait plaisir à entendre*** !" vs "En voilà une idée ***qui fait plaisir à entendre*** !" ... even if you can express the same idea more concisely: "***Voilà qui*** fait plaisir à entendre !"

Comment: *En voilà une idée qu'elle est bonne*, popularized if not invented by Coluche, is now a set expression only used for humorous effects. You might create a variation like yours but that's of course still very incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*En voilà une idée qu'elle est bonne !* est une expression populaire assez courante, mais tout à fait agrammaticale. Elle présente une sorte d'amalgame entre la relative « en voilà une idée qui est bonne » et l'exclamative « cette idée, qu'elle est bonne ! ». Avec comme point de départ du point de vue sémantique l'exclamation : « En voilà une bonne idée ! », qui, elle, ne contient aucun sous-entendu.

Personnellement je ne trouve pas que l'emploi de cette expression exprime une quelconque emphase, mais c'est tout simplement une façon populaire (mais pas vulgaire) de s'exprimer avec une pointe d'humour, voire d'ironie. Voir l'emploi dans [ce débat](http://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/12/cri/2005-2006/20060130.asp) à l'Assemblée Nationale (2006) :

> En voilà une idée qu’elle est bonne (**Sourires** sur les bancs du groupe de l’Union pour un mouvement populaire.)

Je n'ai pas toujours connu cette expression et je ne trouve aucune occurrence antérieure aux années 80. Il me semble que c'est une création de l'humoriste [Coluche](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coluche) mais je ne connais pas assez ses sketches pour dire quand et comment il l'a employée pour la première fois.  Quand on trouve l'expression par écrit, c'est soit dans des dialogues :

> T'as raison ! Comme on t'a bien aidé, tu nous la prêteras un peu s'esclaffe Jacques en tapant sur l'épaule de Gaétan qui éclate de rire à son tour.
> — **En voilà une idée qu'elle est bonne !**
> — Vous êtes aussi con l'un que l'autre répond Fabien en faisant semblant d'être en colère. (Jean-Pierre Grotti - [*L'étang de Pauline*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Nnu1DQAAQBAJ&pg=PT81&dq=%22En%20voil%C3%A0%20une%20id%C3%A9e%20qu%27elle%20est%20bonne%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22En%20voil%C3%A0%20une%20id%C3%A9e%20qu%27elle%20est%20bonne%22&f=false) - 2015)

soit comme citation directe de Coluche :

> Faire un réunion, **en voilà une idée qu'elle est bonne aurait ironisé Coluche**, tandis que pour de nombreux cadres cet énoncé ressemble à une formule diabolique. ([L'Usine Nouvelle](http://www.usinenouvelle.com/article/et-si-on-faisait-une-reunion.N490019) - 24/01/2017 )
>
> **Comme disait Coluche : « En voilà une idée qu’elle est bonne !** » Le gouvernement lance le projet « Soyons clairs ». Il s’agit, en gros, d’encourager les administrations et services publics à s’adresser au citoyen dans un langage qu’il peut comprendre. ([L'Humanité](http://www.humanite.fr/soyons-clairs-604636),14 Avril 2016)

S'il m'arrive d'employer l'expression à l'oral quand je parle de façon tout à fait informelle, je ne l'emploierais pas par écrit dans un texte à tenue professionnelle.

Il serait bien sûr possible de calquer d'autres expression sur le même modèle (« En voilà une idée qu'elle fait plaisir à entendre ! »)  bien que je n'en ai jamais entendu, mais elles seraient aussi comprises comme étant ironiques par rapport à l'expression normale « Voilà qui fait plaisir à entendre ! », qui ne cache aucun sous-entendu.

Answer (score 0):

It's from Coluche.

It's the silly accumulation of :

What a great idea !
+
Here is one good idea !

So it's kind of like saying :

--> Here is one 'what a great' idea !

In Coluche's mouth and with kind of a goofy tone of voice added, it clearly sounded purposefully accumulative just to highlight his irony in a silly way, meaning that the idea he refers to is either useless, bad, or just as silly as the way he commented it.

Also, since then, many people can use it just to be silly, as a shared reference to Coluche, even if they think an idea is good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE Cécile.  Does this add more information than the given answer which mentions Coluche ?